# Swift parse JSON from url

Tags: json, swift, nsurlsession, nsjsonserialization

am very to new to swift and i am trying to parse JSON form a url. I am receiving the object but it is being returned as a bunch of numbers. How do I decode these numbers into the actual object.

```
let requestURL: NSURL =  NSURL(string: "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=06f4ca4cd5f26636e0ac8eebce5b8773&query=fight+club&callback=testing&_=1456113299076")!

let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
(data, response, error) -> Void in

let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

if (statusCode == 200) {

    if (statusCode == 200) {

        do{
            print(data)
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)



        }catch {
            print("Error with Json: \(error)")

        }

    }

}
}
task.resume()
```

Answer (score 1):

An error occurs with error message

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Something looked like a
>   'true' but wasn't around character 0."

That means the string is not valid JSON (wrongly formatted) right from the beginning.

**Solution:**

For some incomprehensible reason the JSON string is wrapped in a `testing(...)` block.

You need to trim the data from byte 9 (index 8) until second to last.

```
do{
    let trimmedData = data!.subdataWithRange(NSRange(location:8, length: data!.length - 9))
    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(trimmedData, options: .AllowFragments)
    print(json)
  }
  ...
```

PS: **In the completion block it's highly recommended to check if the error is not `nil` before getting the `statusCode`**